# Setting Image on the JTextField in Swing Java Netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, background-image, jtextfield

I am using Netbeans And trying to set BackGround Image on The JTextField. But how ever I am not able to find that property.
Can anybody Help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the text field to the label. Something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.setOpaque( false );
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
label.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
label.add( textField );
```

Full example [from](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343579/GUI/java/Inserting-Image-JTextField):

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
class Testing extends JFrame  
{  
  public Testing()  
  {  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(5);  
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Test.gif"));  
    label.setOpaque(true);  
    label.setBackground(tf.getBackground());  
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(label.getPreferredSize().width,tf.getPreferredSize().height));  
    p.setBorder(tf.getBorder());  
    tf.setBorder(null);  
    p.add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);  
    p.add(tf,BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();  
    p1.add(p);  
    getContentPane().add(p1);  
    pack();  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args){new Testing().setVisible(true);}  
}
```